# Universal Motor as a magnetic brake

Tags: dc-motor, induction-motor, braking, universal-motor, ac-motor

Hello friends of stackexchange,

I want to make a magnetic brake based on a universal motor from a Candy wash machine TYPE 20584.528. I suppose that the best way is to use the motor as a DC generator using the field winding as a permanent magnet and extract the current from the rotor winding, the issue that I have is that I havent found any datasheet from de motor for kwowing the maximun voltage I can use in the winding so not destroy the isolation. Also I want to calculate the disipation power for calculating the resistance that I need as a load for closing the rotor circuit and act as a brake.

The field windings are connected in the way that there is three cables and the resistance is gray-brown 2 Ohm, gray-black 1.3 Ohm and black-brown 1.3 Ohm I suposse that is because is a two speed motor, but seems to be conected in triangle way.[image]

[image]

too I want to know if it possible to use a counter current for incresasing the resistance and how to do it, having always in mind that heat can destroy the windings.

The purpose of all this mess is to implement a bike roller with magnetic brake  that could be great for these quarantine days.

So thanks in advance and be free to give any advice suggestion.

Comment: universal motor can't be used as generator.

Comment: @Marko _”using the field winding as a permanent magnet”_ I interpret it as OP plan to break the connection to the rotor and supply external bias.

Comment: I think that Universal motor can be used as DC motor so they can be used as a alternator otherwise generator.

Comment: @Marko in this kind of motors the conection between the rotor and the field is not done you have to setup the configuration so are so versatile these motors, you can supply the external (estator) windings and create the field

Comment: Then, this is not an universal motor. It's rather a Separately Excited DC Motor.

Comment: yes it changes the type of electric machine that it is, but it's a very minor modification, you only need to cut one wire and connect terminals..

Answer (score 1):

The idea of supplying a fixed DC voltage to the field from a separate power supply seems like a good plan. The original machine very likely had at least the rated current marked on it. The motor seems to have the voltage marked on it and perhaps also the power. There may have also been a diagram of the internal control circuits on the back of the machine. Since the field would have been connected in series with the armature, the field current would be whatever the original motor current rating was. From that and the field resistance you can figure how much voltage is required to produce the proper field current. It is probably best to operate it with no load on the armature to start with. Then measure the voltage output and figure out the load resistance from that.

Comment: I think that is the way the problem is that for having enough torque whith a domestic power supply nor a battery I haven´t it. In this Motor as you see in the picture there is no specifications, only the ac voltage and two rpm 480/1700 so its been very difficult to test whiout the risk of harming it.

Comment: I can not read 480/1700 RPM on that picture of the label. Those speeds do not sound right for a universal motor. Are you sure this motor has a commutator?

Comment: (`can not read 480/1700` above the barcode wait, I read *17000*)